# Swift - Table View cell spacing to left and right border

Tags: swift, uitableview

I created this table view cell.

[image]

But I'm struggling to add a spacing to the left and right border like in the app store. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow @Tobi, you should take a `UIView` from 12 px left, 12 px right, 12 px top & 12 px bottom

Comment: You need to add constraints to your view on both the `leading` and `trailing` edges. This will give you some room around, at whatever spacing you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You must make UIView inside the Content View and add constraint to the UIView like this:
[image]